# Find the IVP solution to the following differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Give the general solution to the following differential equation and use the general solution to solve this initial value problem:
>   $$y''-y=0,\quad  
> y(1)=1+e,\quad y'
> (1)=-1+e,
> \quad y=e^{rt}$$

I found that the general solution is equal to

$$y(t)=C_1e^{-t} + C_2e^{t}$$

However I'm not sure how to find the solution to the initial value problem. I thought that $C_1=1$ and $C_2=-1$ might be the solution.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Welcome to math.stackexchange. Please use MathJax when formatting your questions. https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference On this exercise you should substitute the initial values into the solution. This gives two linear algebraic equations which you solve for $C_1$ and $C_2$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start with taking the derivative of your general solution and then plug in the respective initial values.

Comment: Was that helpful?